# Associativity of Quaternion after Multiplication

Tags: quaternions

I need to rotate quaternion -90 degree around Y-axis. So, I am using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436764/rotating-a-quaternion-on-1-axis for it. Now I have below case,

I am getting multiplication of two quaternion **Q1** and **Q2** instead of seprate Q1 and Q2. So, Now how to rotate this multiplied quaternion.

As what I want is **Q1-rotated** * **Q2-rotated** but I am getting **Q1 * Q2**, which I can do is **((Q1 * Q2)-rotated)** which is not right. As I can't change order of multiplication in quaternion i.e. Q1 * Q2 != Q2 * Q1, which means **(Q1*rotation) * (Q2*rotation) != (Q1*Q2) * (rotation*rotation)**.

So basically I am having **Q1 * Q2** and I want **Q1-rotated** * **Q2-rotated** where I know **rotation**.

Please suggest some way to solve this.

**Update**

I have result of **(Q1 * Q2)** and **unit_rotating_quaternion** and I want is **(Q1*unit_rotating_quaternion) * (Q2*unit_rotating_quaternion)**, So Is there any way to find it ?

Comment: If you **only** have $Q1*Q2$ then you can **not** get $Q1$ and $Q2$ from the product.

Comment: Yes that's true, but Is there any quaternion exist like, **(Q1 * Q2) * unit_rotating_quaternion * some_quaternion_to_multiply** which will give same result as **(Q1*unit_rotating_quaternion) * (Q2*unit_rotating_quaternion)**.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a unit rotating quaternion and $q$ is quaternion to be rotated, then
$$
q'= pqp^{-1}.
$$

You have $Q=q_1q_2$ and $q'_1=pq_1p^{-1}$, $q_2' = pq_2p^{-1}$, so:
$$
Q'=q'_1q_2'=pq_1p^{-1}pq_2p^{-1} = pq_1q_2p^{-1} = pQp^{-1}
$$
as expected.

Comment: Your answer helped me for understanding clearly. But If I rotate (Q1*Q2) using unit rotating quaternion and after that If I am finding difference between (Q1-rotated*Q2-rotated) and (Q1*Q2)-rotated using **diff = q2 * inverse(q1)** then I am getting difference of **x=-0.7071, y=0.0, z=0.7071, w=0** sometimes this diff is changing as  **x=0.7071, y=0.0, z=-0.7071, w=0**. Can you help me out with this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Sorry

Comment: As per your answer I understood, If I want **Q1-rotated * Q2-rotated** from **Q1*Q2** than I can directly multiply unit rotation quaternion to **Q1*Q2**. In such case If I find difference using formula **diff = (Q1-rotated * Q2-rotated) * inverse((Q1*Q2)*rotated)** must not come as **x=-0.7071, y=0.0, z=0.7071, w=0** which I am getting and also **diff** is sometimes **changing** to **x=0.7071, y=0.0, z=-0.7071, w=0**. So I might be doing something wrong in this. Can you please help me understanding how I am getting difference in this?

Comment: I still cant understand what you are doing. What problem are you trying to solve? What are Q1 and Q2? Why do you need to rotate them? Why do you need to take the diff? It will help if you first consider carefully everything you are trying to achieve (draw pictures), and then formulate your question. We cant debug the equations for you.

Comment: I also know you will not debug for me. Anyway you proved associativity. What question I asked is different, In which I know multiplication of two quaternion Q1 & Q2. And I want to find **Q1-rotated * Q2-rotated**. If I know Q1 & Q2 separately than I will do like **Q1*unit_rotating_quaternion * Q2*unit_rotating_quaternion** but I have **(Q1 * Q2)** so If I do **(Q1 * Q2) * unit_rotating_quaternion** that will not give me what I want. So I am taking difference just for checking, if it is giving result what I want to do or not.